# Invariance in causally disentangled factorizations

Tags: bayesian, causality, invariance

In the paper ["Towards Causal Representation Learning"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11107), Schölkopf et al. give the following argument for causally disentangled factorizations:

> consider a dataset that consists of altitude $A$ and average annual temperature $T$ of weather stations. $A$ and $T$ are correlated, which we believe is due to the fact that the altitude has a causal effect on temperature. Suppose we had two such datasets, one for Austria and one for Switzerland. The two joint distributions $P(A, T)$ may be rather different since the marginal distributions $P(A)$ over altitudes will differ. The conditionals $P(T \mid A)$, however, may be (close to) invariant, since they characterize the physical mechanisms that generate temperature from altitude. This similarity is lost upon us if we only look at the overall joint distribution, without information about the causal structure $A \rightarrow T$. The causal factorization $P(A)P(T \mid A)$ will contain a component $P(T \mid A)$ that generalizes across countries, while the entangled factorization $P(T)P(A \mid T)$ will exhibit no such robustness.

It is not obvious to me why this is true. Surely, both $P(T \mid A)$ and $P(A \mid T)$ will capture the relationship between altitude and temperature, so why is only $P(T \mid A)$ robust to a change in $P(A)$ while $P(A \mid T)$ is not? In other words, why should temperature become a worse predictor of altitude just because the landscape changed?

Bengio et al. make the same point in the paper ["A Meta-Transfer Objective for Learning to Disentangle Causal Mechanisms"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10912) and mention that it is due to Bayes' theorem:

> On the other hand, because of Bayes’ rule, under the incorrect model ($B \rightarrow A)$, a change in $P(A)$ leads to new parameters for both $P(B)$ and $P(A \mid B)$.

However, I fail to see how this follows from Bayes' theorem.

I'd appreciate anyone who can help. I'm sure the answer is pretty basic and I just can't see the forest for the trees.